# What happens after a green dragonborn uses their breath weapon?

Tags: dnd-5e, racial-traits, dragonborn, breath-weapon

When a green dragonborn uses its breath weapon, which is a 15 ft. cone of poison gas, what are the lingering effects that would happen? Since the elemental damage of the breath weapon is based on their dragon color, and the [green dragon is a poison gas cloud](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/adult-green-dragon), what possible effects may follow?

Examples include, but are not limited to:

- Does a cloud linger if it's not a well ventilated area?
- Can they (or a black dragonborn) start bottling their breath weapon?
- Is there a possibility of the cloud diffusing and harming a larger area?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

#### Everything you need to know about the breath weapon is in the trait description.

In particular, the Breath Weapon trait says:

> When you use your breath weapon, each creature in the area of the exhalation must make a saving throw, the type of which is determined by your draconic ancestry. The DC for this saving throw equals 8 + your Constitution modifier + your proficiency bonus. A creature takes 2d6 damage on a failed save, and half as much damage on a successful one.

This is the entirety of the Breath Weapon’s effect. If it lingered around to have further effects later it would say so. It does not say it hangs around, so it does not hang around.

It is worth pointing out that the breath weapon is never described as a cloud of sorts. Rather, it says:

> You can use your action to exhale destructive energy.

So the green Dragonborn’s Breath Weapon is not a cloud of poisonous gas, but rather a cone of poisonous “destructive energy”, whatever that means.

So to answer your questions directly, we have:

> Does a cloud linger if it's not a well ventilated area?

No.

> Can they (or a black dragonborn) start bottling their breath weapon?

No.

> Is there a possibility of the cloud diffusing and harming a larger area?

No.

The idea here is that there is supposed to be some equity between the different colors of dragonborn in terms of mechanics. If one color starts being able to do extra stuff the other colors cannot that color becomes a more attractive choice of color. The several times I have DM'd for dragonborn PCs I have used the damage type of the breath weapon to inform the narrative descriptions of the breath weapon but never offered any additional benefits based on the damage type because *all the colors are supposed to be the same except for damage type and area of effect shape.*

For what it's worth, this idea is something of a design principle of 5th Edition. [Jeremy Crawford, lead rules designer, once tweeted, saying](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/857269923134939136):

> Beware of claims that a rule does something mentioned nowhere in that rule or elsewhere in the core books. There aren't secret rules. #DnD

There is nowhere in any sourcebook that says a dragonborn's breath weapon does anything other than what I have quoted above, so that's all it does.

Comment: "Destructive Energy" is because they are encompassing several elements into one umbrella. If you compare it to the green dragon, the breath weapon is poison gas

Comment: Dragonborn are not dragons. But it doesn’t really matter, the feature description has all of its effects. There are no other effects than what is written.

Comment: I know they aren't literal dragons, although I'm sure you would have no problem describing any of the other breaths as being literal interpretations of their elements and not just some video game energy wave

Comment: @CatLord Speaking of other dragonborn breaths, none of the other breath weapons have reason to linger around, and there's supposed to be some sense of equity between the colors of dragonborn. The whole idea is that the breath weapons all behave the same way, except for damage type and area of effect shape.

Comment: If I were asking about a red dragonborn, would your reply consider that things may have been set on fire, or that a room could get warmer?

Comment: @CatLord No. Features that involve fire state when they set things on fire. For example, *fireball* includes this statement in its spell description: "It ignites flammable objects in the area that aren't being worn or carried."

Comment: Thomas is correct here. A fire-breathing dragonborn technically can't use their breath to ignite a campfire. A DM could (and probably should) allow it, but that's by DM fiat, not by the rules as written, and it should be done carefully to avoid making one kind of breath weapon "the best" or set a precedent that will allow some kind of crazy effect later. You can see similar "the rules don't say so" effects among other spells, like how *lightning bolt* ignites flammable objects in its area, but *call lightning* doesn't.

Comment: @CatLord D&D isn't exactly a game that will always prize realism over game mechanics. It makes sense that poison gas could potentially linger in the air or spread out, just like it'd make sense that a lizardfolk could be able to stack up ACs instead of having to choose between their natural armor and any other armor. Both cases however would make some options (regarding races and subraces) inherently better than others. It's also one of the reasons PC natural weapons aren't all that strong when compared to those of monsters or to actual weapons.